# Question about Fekete polynomials evaluated at $-1$.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, roots-of-unity

Let $p$ be an odd prime, $k = (p-1)/2$, and $\zeta$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity.  The Fekete polynomial is defined to be
\begin{equation*}
f_p(t)= \sum_{a = 1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{a}{p} \right) t^a
\end{equation*}
where $\left(\frac{a}{p} \right)$ is the Legendre symbol.  It is known that
\begin{equation*}
f_p(\zeta^k)= \epsilon_p\sqrt{p} \left(\frac{k}{p}\right)
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
\epsilon_p =
\begin{cases} 
1 &\text{ if } p \equiv 1 \mod 4
\\
i &\text{ if } p \equiv 3 \mod 4
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Now, if $p$ is a large prime congruent to $3$ mod $4$, then we have that $\zeta^k$ is close to  $-1$ in the complex plane, and since $f_p(t)$ is continuous we also have that $f_p(\zeta^k) = \sqrt{-p}\left(\frac{k}{p}\right) \approx f_p(-1)$.  But this seems to be impossible since $f_p(-1) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $f_p(\zeta^k)$ is far up or down the imaginary axis.  There must be something stupid that I'm missing here but I can't figure out what it is....

Comment: So you have proven that $f_p'(t)$ is large between $1$ and $\zeta^k$

Comment: @reuns I see.  I was thinking that this violated continuity, but I forgot that I'm not looking at a fixed $f_p$ as $p$ gets larger.  Whoops!  Thank you.